# error using copy from in postgresql when value is '2"%'

Tags: mysql, postgresql, postgresql-copy

I have a table with 300,000 rows not under my control that I need to import.

I export the data from mysql using:

```sh
mysqldump -u root --password=secret --fields-enclosed-by='\"' -T/tmp apflora_beob
```

Then I try to import each table using for example:

```
\copy beob_evab FROM '/Users/alex/tmp/beob_evab.txt' (FORMAT 'csv', DELIMITER E'\t', NULL '\N', ESCAPE E'\"', ENCODING 'UTF8');
```

This works for most tables, also for one containing 450,000 rows. But on one I get this error:

> ```
> ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(10)
> CONTEXT:  COPY beob_evab, line 190310, column COUV_MOUSSES: "2\%  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  30  \N  15  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  \N  0.01  \N  \N
> Bachs, Dau..."
> ```

When I check field `COUV_MOUSSES` in line 190'310 it contains this value: `2"%`.

What would I have to change to get this to work?

In order to achieve the correct output `"2""%"` according to @klin (thanks!) I would have to do add `--fields-escaped-by='"'` to the mysqldump command. So that becomes:

```sh
mysqldump -u root --password=secret --fields-enclosed-by='"' --fields-escaped-by='"' -T/tmp apflora_beob
```

Problem is: now Null values are exported as `"N`.

Well, no problem, I thought and changed the copy command to:

```
\copy beob_evab FROM '/Users/alex/tmp/beob_evab.txt' (FORMAT 'csv', DELIMITER E'\t', NULL '"N', ESCAPE "'", ENCODING 'UTF8');
```

This produces the following error in Postgres:

> ```
> ERROR:  CSV quote character must not appear in the NULL specification
> ```

And it seems that the representation of Null values can not be changed in MySQL.

Comment: Shouldn't be `mysqldump -u root --password=secret --fields-enclosed-by='"' -T/tmp apflora_beob`?

Comment: yeah `--fields-enclosed-by='"'` works too. Seems that it works the same as `--fields-enclosed-by='\"'`. But does not prevent MySQL from exporting `"N` as null values

Comment: I mean: `mysqldump -u root --password=secret --fields-enclosed-by='"' --fields-escaped-by='\\' -T/tmp apflora_beob`

Comment: according to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html that is standard behavior, same as not using `--fields-escaped-by='\\'. And the same error happens as mentioned in the original question

Comment: I've tried this mysqldump and it seems really stubborn. Maybe you should do some post processing with `sed` (`"N\t -> \\N\t` or something similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value should be written down as

```
"2""%"
```

Per [RFC 4180 - Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#page-2):

> [5].  Each field may or may not be enclosed in double quotes (however
> some programs, such as Microsoft Excel, do not use double quotes
> at all).  If fields are not enclosed with double quotes, then
> double quotes may not appear inside the fields.(...)
>
> [7].  If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
> appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
> another double quote.  For example:
>
> ```
>    "aaa","b""bb","ccc"
> ```

Comment: thanks a lot. Please see the edited part of my question

Comment: yep, this works when I combine it with replacing all `"N` with `\N`. Thanks a lot!